# DB mail sending attachment of size 64 KB only even after increasing maximum file size limit

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I am facing an issue with DB mail functionality. I am using SQL Server Agent to trigger mail on success or failure. While sending this, I am also providing an attachment, which consists of some query-generated report.

The problem here is I am able to send mail with attachment but the attachment size is fixed to 64Kb only. I have increased maximum attachment size limit from Database mail configuration, still the same problem exists.

I am executing following lines of code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = @profileName,
    @recipients = @recipientsList,
    @body = @Body,
    @subject = @Subject ,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query= @Query,
    @query_attachment_filename=@EmailFileName,
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1,
    @query_result_separator= ' '
```

Comment: What is the original file size, and is it curtailing the file/somehow to 64kb,  or increasing it to a constant 64kb?

Comment: File size can go in MB's. Actualy it's curtailing the file to 64KB and not increasing offcourse. SQL server version used is 2014.

Comment: is it something with the actual exchange/outlook file size limit? beyond sql server? not sure

Comment: i don't think so, as the attachments which can be sent through exchange/outlook has been provided with a file size limit of atleast 10-15 MB.There is something else... :(

Comment: I'm thinking you may be running into something else, as well. SQL Server would have been defaulted to 1MB attachments. So at a minimum, you should be seeing that file size. Also, SQL Server will give you an error if you attempt to attach something larger than the configured value. If you're getting the email, then I think it's sending the full file over. Are you able to open the 64KB attachment (i.e. it's not the result of a virus scanner intercepting it)?

Comment: As i have already mentioned I have increased attachment size to 10 Mb's so there is no point getting error like 'something larger than the configured value'. I am getting mail but its not full file as I can see by querying into database that it has 4000 rows but in excel I am getting only 320,so obviously it cutting my attachment for some reason.Yea I am able to Open that file,also I can see a word cut into half since 64 KB's got completed.So there is something that stopping to attach a full file.

Comment: While further investigation I found this 'https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/PrintTopic1589664.aspx' .Discussion shows there is bug in 2014.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply [Cumulative update package 4 for SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999197). There was a bug which was fixed in CU4.

**Symptoms**

> Assume that you use Database Mail and sp_send_dbmail stored procedure
>   with the @query and @attach_query_result_as_file option in Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2014. The stored procedure run a query and set the
>   result-set as an attachment of the email. When the query has a large
>   result-set, the attachment is truncated to 64 kilobyte (KB) maximum.

**Resolution**

> The issue was first fixed in the following cumulative update of SQL
>   Server.

Details in below link:

[FIX: "sp_send_dbmail" stored procedure truncates email attachments to 64 KB in SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004195/fix-sp-send-dbmail-stored-procedure-truncates-email-attachments-to-64)

Comment: Is this fix require any service or database restart or SQL server restart,as this issue is on Production server??

Comment: 'The version of SQL Server instance Shared Component does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update.
The installed SQL Server product version is 12.0.2000.8, and the expected SQL Server version is 12.2.5000.0.' I don't find any such version available on link you provided.

Comment: If there are no pending reboot from a earlier update/installation you do not need a service restart. What is the build number of your SQL server?  Do you already have SP2 installed?

Comment: Installing SP2 worked for me.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing SQL Server 2014 SP2 resolved my problem...Available at below mentioned URL.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168

Configuring my Database mail to increase the maximum attachment limit and Installing SP2 worked for me. Now,able to attach files of size 4MB and more.